# Undefined array key error in my php list?

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am developing file upload based on selected dropdown which will open and read file and based on file content data would be stored inside stored procedure..
I am doing this with the help of php and sql server 2012 i am getting undefined error.
I am unable to resolve this error even after trying several times.
Any help would be highly appreciated you can also edit my code.
I am sharing required php code with the errors which I am getting

```
$file = fopen("$target_file","r");

while(!feof($file)) {
    $content = fgets($file);

    $carray = explode(",",$content);

    list($INPUTXML,$UserName,$PosCode,$Password,$UserID,$CompanyID,$BranchID,$TerminalType,$UserType,$LOCADD) = $carray;

    $sql = "{CALL ITPAN_UPDATE (@INPUTXML= ?, @UserName= ?, @PosCode= ?, @Password= ?, @UserID= ?, @CompanyID= ?, @BranchID=
    ?,@TerminalType= ?,@UserType=?,@LOCADD=?)}";

    $params = array( 
        array(&$INPUTXML, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
        array(&$UserName, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
        array(&$PosCode, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
        array(&$Password, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),   
        array(&$UserID, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
        array(&$CompanyID, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN), 
        array(&$BranchID, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
        array(&$TerminalType, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
        array(&$UserType, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
        array(&$LOCADD, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    );

    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql,$params);

    if ($result === false) {
        echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        exit;
    }

    //  while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        //echo print_r($row, true);
    // }

    if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo print_r($row,true);
    }

    if (!sqlsrv_execute($result)) {
        echo "Your code is failing!";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); // will throw error if my procedure is not getting executed ..
    }

    fclose($file);  //closes the file
    sqlsrv_close($conn); // closes the sql connection 
}
```

Comment: Which line is triggering the error?

Comment: @JacobMulquin   list($INPUTXML,$UserName,$PosCode,$Password,$UserID,$CompanyID,$BranchID,$TerminalType,$UserType,$LOCADD) = $carray;

Comment: OK so that indicates that `$carray` does not have the same number of elements as what the `list()` function is expecting. Check your target file for any lines that may have missing data. You can add a `echo count($carray) . PHP_EOL;continue;` after the `explode()` function to check the number of elements in each line.